# Google Service Account key(json) and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-api, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-translate, service-accounts

I am running an application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and would like to use the Google Cloud Translation API. From what I can understand the only option for authentication is a Google Service Account.

https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth

From this link is says to store the json file securely. How do I do that but still have it accessible by my application? From what I know everything in Elastic Beanstalk is published to the web. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What programming language are you using in your app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your website backend is implemented, you could store the file in a secure S3 bucket and read the contents from your application at runtime.

Comment: Thanks that looks like it would work but I decided to use an API key instead.

Comment: Hi @Craig, where you able to restrict access with your implementation?

Comment: @Devmaleeq at the time it was not the best, as anyone who got the API key could use it. These days you could add access for the IAM instance profile to access S3 so your app can access the file without the file being publicly available.

Comment: True. You can also utilize AWS Secure manager, as long as you plan to load it using EB Hooks incase of redeployment or configuraiton changes